# Find all classes that are not @Autowired

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I have a big spring web application which uses annotations. However, there are some classes which are annotated with @component/service but are not autowired from where they are called. Instead, new operator is used.

I want to find out all such instances of user-defined classes where the new operator is used.

Basically, I created a new Http wrapper class (spring component) and I'm having it called from multiple places in the application. Some place it works because the auto wiring to it works because the containing class and the classes from the beginning of the chain are managed by spring. But some places it doesn't work because one of the classes in the calling chain was instantiated using new and is not spring managed. So I want to fix this and make such classes are also spring managed.

I'm talking about 100s of classes, so please suggest a tool or method that can be done in 3-4 hours and prevents human errors. I use eclipse.

Example:

```
@Component
public class MyHttpClient {

    public int execute() {
        ...
    }
}

@Component
public class UtilC {

    @Autowired
    private MyHttpClient client;

    public int methodC() {
        // When methodC is called from A, it works
        // but when called from B, it gives NullPointerException
        client.execute();
    }
}

@Component
public class UtilB {

    private UtilC c = new UtilC();

    public int methodB() {
        c.methodC();
    }
}

@Component
public class UtilA {

    @Autowired
    private UtilC c;

    public int methodA() {
        c.methodC();
    }
}
```

Please do not suggest this:

```
 @Component
 public class UtilC {

     @Autowired
     private MyHttpClient client;

     public int methodC() {
         try {
             client.execute();
         } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
             new MyHttpClient.execute();
         }
     }
 }
```

How do I search for all the user defined classes which are instantiated like new UtilC

Comment: Are they well named like `SomeService` such that you could write a regex for it?

Comment: The Call Hierarchy (Ctrl-Alt-H) can't tell you who calls the constructor? If the object is supposed to be Spring-managed, then nobody should call the constructor, except Spring, and that won't show since Spring uses reflection to do so. If you don't have a constructor to use Call Hierarchy on, temporarily create one.

Comment: No, they are not well defined as to write the regex for them. Can I search instance variables of user-defined classes in eclipse that use a new operator?

Comment: A combination of `find` and `grep` should do the trick.  Read the manual entries.  (Maybe `xargs` too.)

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Google reflection](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reflections/) to find all the classes annotated with `@Autowired`

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("org.home.xxx");
Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired.class);
```

The classes does not present in the `Set` is not annotated.

Comment: I need to know all the user defined classes that are not present in the set.

Comment: Is there a way I can list out all user defined classes in my application and then I can compare with the ones which are in the set. If they are not in the set then it means they are not autowired?

Answer (score 0):

If you have "a big spring web application which uses annotations", you must be using a proper Java IDE. Every IDE has this feature called "Find Usages" (or something similar). You should use that.

For example, with Intellij IDEA, here's how I'd do it:

1. Locate the `Autowired` interface (in the source code). Use "Find Usages". [image]
2. It should show you the usages (nicely categorized in terms of the *kinds* of usages).[image]

Comment: This will give me classes that are autowired. How would it give me User-definedclasses that were instantiated using new operator

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this would be the usage of aspectj (compile-time-weaving). for example the following aspects lets the compiler create errors for ctor of classes that are annotated with @XmlRootElement usages (but during runtime a container can of course call it reflectively)

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public aspect CtorError {

    declare error : call ((@XmlRootElement *).new(..)) : "ctor called";
}
```